# Firefox: manually allow website (whitelist whole domain) to allow camera and microphone access

Tags: linux, firefox, permissions, website, microphone

I regularly partake in videoconferences that are browser-based only. Despite there being a permanent URL to access a room, each session is given a different ID with its own subdomain (to which one is automatically forwarded from the permanent URL upon joining). I.e.:

Enter via:

```
 https://example.com/ROOM
```

Actual session under:

```
 https://SESSION-ID.example.com
```

with changing `SESSION-ID`

The problem now is that Firefox (v. 84 on Linux Mint 20) will allow camera and microphone access based on the WHOLE DOMAIN, i.e. including the changing session ID, forcing me to grant access by new each time. The main domain itself never asks for permission to use cam+mic.

**Is there a way in firefox to whitelist a whole domain (`example.com`) and its subdomains to grant access to camera and microphone?**

Under preferences -> privacy & security -> permissions -> camera (or microphone), one may only review known websites and change permissions or delete a website, but no way to manually add an entry not alter the know URLs.

How to create a whitelist? No limitations regarding installation of add-ons.

PS: So far I have only seen ways to suppress the permission prompt altogether by setting `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to true (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1452822/471276)) - but maybe there is a more finely grained alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is currently impossible in Firefox.

I found out this parameter is stored in your profiles main catalog folder permissions.sqlite file. You can find path to the folder by visiting about:profiles in the adress bar. File can be opened via sqlite client of your choice (I used DBeaver).

This value resides in permissions.sqlite.moz_perms table. You can add https://example.com with permission 1 value, and it will show up in preferences window, but Firefox will ignore this value and keep asking for permissions per subdomain.
Also tried hacking this using * wildcard, no success.